# Firebase push notification for both web and android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notifications for both Android, iOS and now I'm building a web app.

To open the app from a notification you need a click_action that matches the `<action name.../>` in the `<intent-filter>`. To open the web app from a notification you need a valid URL.

It seems impossible to find a solution that works for both Android and web. I've tried to skip the `<action>` element all together and just use a `category` and a `data` element instead, but this does not seem to work.

How can I make this work? The only thing I can think of right now is to keep track of what platform each token belongs to and send different notifications to Android users and web users. Is there a better way?

Comment: You might want to proofread your question.  The second sentence doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks. Some stuff got lost when not tagging it as code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're refering to the payload structure, I think you're looking for [Platform Overrides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing_a_message_across_platforms).

This gives you the option to have different values intended for a platform without knowing what the token is associated with.

Comment: Thanks for that. That looked very promising, but I could not get it to work. The documentation doesn't seem to have any "click_action" for webpush, even though it does work for the global notification object.

Comment: I ended up sending two notifications, one for app users and one for web users. I don't use topics in this case, so that worked pretty well.